# Get the ID of every element where required = true

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of many select or input and i want to get the id of each of them who have "required=true"
here's the beginning of my code

```
function getRequiredFieldsId(contenerId)
{
    // Detection of all select fields
    let objFields = document.getElementById(contenerId).getElementsByTagName('select');
    let q=1;
}
```

I maybe need to do a forEach but i don't really know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use .querySelectorAll("[required]") to get all required element

then if you want only id you can use map

```
[...requiredElements].map(element => element.id);
```

```js
function getRequiredFieldsId(contenerId)
{
    let requiredElements = document.getElementById(contenerId).querySelectorAll("[required]");
    requiredElementsId = [...requiredElements].map(element => element.id);
    console.log(requiredElementsId);
}

getRequiredFieldsId('container1');
```

```html
<div id="container1">
  <input id="test1"/>
  <input id="test2" required/>
  <input id="test3" required/>
</div>

<div id="container2">
  <input id="test1" required/>
  <input id="test2"/>
  <input id="test3"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns an array like collection. So you will have to make it an array using `...` (spread operator), for easy iteration.

After that checking `required` property is all you have to do.

Building up on your code:

```js
let items = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
let reqItems = [];
[...items].forEach(x => {
if(x.required) reqItems.push(x);
});
console.log(reqItems);
```

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars" required>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select name="cars2" id="cars2" required>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select name="cars3" id="cars3">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select name="cars4" id="cars4" required>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.querySelector` function for retrieving conditional DOM elements. E.g

```
let elems = document.querySelectorAll('select[required=true],input[required=true]');
```

With this you will have all the elements met this condition.
With the `.map function` you will receive all the ids.

```
let ids = [...elems].map(item => element.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for that

```js
const requiredInputSelector = `input[required=true]`;
const requiredInputs = document.querySelectorAll(requiredInputSelector);
const requiredInputIds = [...requiredInputs].map((field) => field.id);

console.log({requiredInputIds})
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<input required="true" id="id-0">
<input required="true" id="id-1">
<input required="false" id="id-2">
<input id="id-3">
<input required="true" id="id-4">
</body>
</html>
```